# Failed to start daemon for power management

Tags: hard-drive, 21.04

Sometimes when I shut down it hangs at the message `[failed] failed to start daemon for power management`. I've looked to see if this problem has happened before in 20.04 or later. But I didn't find it. I have an extra built-in SSD which is seen as `/share`. I have 2 SSD 2TB `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`.

I have tried `sudo apt install systemd:amd64 systemd-timesyncd:amd64` but they are already up to date.

I have no idea what to look for to prevent this. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I may have the same problem with 20.10 on an Asus Aspire 5332 laptop. A second or two after the POST, disk activity stops. I found a couple of solutions:

1. The laptop boots OK if I remove the battery and run the laptop using the mains power supply - Which rather defeats the reason for owning a mobile device!
2. After staring at a blank screen for 5 mins, I pressed Ctrl-C which (coincidently?) got the boot going again.

I'm guessing that there's more going on than meets the eye, but it's w-a-y beyond my pay grade :-/

The 'Important' Log said that org.bluez had timed out, but if I look at what happened at 9:43:12 ...

```
 9:48:39 AM dbus-update-act: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
 9:48:39 AM systemd: Started Daemon for power management.
 9:48:39 AM dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower'
 9:48:39 AM xhost: localuser:sash being added to access control list
 9:48:38 AM systemd: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
 9:48:38 AM Xsession: /etc/gdm3/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
 9:48:38 AM Xorg: (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
 9:48:38 AM systemd-timesyn: Initial synchronization to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
 9:43:12 AM systemd: Starting Daemon for power management...
 9:43:12 AM dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' unit='upower.service' requested by ':1.38' (uid=1000 pid=847 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
 9:43:12 AM systemd: Started Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor.
 9:43:12 AM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=881] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
 9:43:12 AM systemd: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
 9:43:12 AM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=881] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
```

and

```
$ systemctl status upower.service
● upower.service - Daemon for power management
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/upower.service; disabled; vendor prese>
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-10-16 09:48:39 BST; 51min ago
       Docs: man:upowerd(8)
   Main PID: 962 (upowerd)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 3430)
     Memory: 2.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/upower.service
             └─962 /usr/libexec/upowerd

Oct 16 09:43:12 SASH-Laptop systemd[1]: Starting Daemon for power management...
Oct 16 09:48:39 SASH-Laptop systemd[1]: Started Daemon for power management.
lines 1-12/12 (END)
```